# Which biosynthetic pathways take place in the plastid and were are they located?

Tags: biochemistry, botany, metabolism, plant-physiology, chloroplasts

I know that the isoprenoid, jasmonate, glucosinolate, fatty acids, chlorophyll, starch, and aromatic amino acid syntheses are located in the plastid. But I don't know if they are located in the thylakoidlumen or in the stroma.